# Android Play Games Leaderboard won't show scores

Tags: android, google-play-services, google-play-games, leaderboard

I have added a leaderboard to my published game "DontCross", but when I submit a score, the leaderboard says "Hmm, Something went wrong in Play games", and the button Try again that does nothing.

I have never been able to show any kind of score appearance on the scoreboard.

I have checked my ID, and have looked on the internet for similar problems, but couldn't find a solution.

My game also has Achievement that works perfectly so my connection to Google Play Services wouldn't be the problem.

For submitting code:

```
Games.getLeaderboardsClient(this, GoogleSignIn.getLastSignedInAccount(this))
.submitScore(getString(R.string.leaderboard_scoreboard), (long)prefs.getInt(MyPreferences.LEVEL, 1));
```

For displaying leaderboard:

```
Games.getLeaderboardsClient(this, GoogleSignIn.getLastSignedInAccount(this))
                    .getLeaderboardIntent(getString(R.string.leaderboard_scoreboard))
                    .addOnSuccessListener(intent -> startActivityForResult(intent, 9004));
```

I have tried without and with publishing the leaderboard and I have checked some examples online.

I really don't know what I could have done wrong.
Any help would be greatly appreciated!
Thanks

Comment: https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/games/LeaderboardsClient.LeaderboardScores here it says `It is required to call release() on this object or on the result of getScores() when finished with the LeaderboardScoreBuffer.`

Comment: @madlymad Thanks for your answer but I don't use a LeaderboardscoreBuffer so I wouldn't have any idea where to put it?

Answer (score 0):

I solved my own problem and it was a case of a wrong SHA 1 key. I uploaded the apk on another device so the sha-1 keys didn't match. I tried it again on the same computer and it solved my problem.